# java: ERROR: "cannot find symbol – class Constructor" when making instance from String, with parameters

Tags: java, class, reflection, constructor, instance

I searched through all the questions here that involve 'reflection' to instantiate a parameterised object using a String of the class name, but I cannot get it to work because Java doesn't recognise Constructor as a class.

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("MyClass");

Class[] types = {Double.TYPE, String.TYPE};
Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor(types);

Object[] parameters = {1.0, "hello"};
Object instanceOfMyClass = constructor.newInstance(parameters);
```

This is the code I tried using, I also tried writing the parameters differently, but those are irrelevant to the problem (please reply to the Constructor class issue). How do I make this work?

Comment: and what constructor of which class are you trying to call? do you have the right version of Java/dependencies?

Comment: Add the code of `MyClass`

Comment: @Stultuske what do you mean? It was a class in my project... I can call the constructor the normal manual way just fine.

Comment: so you have a constructor `public MyClass(Double d, String s)`?

Comment: post the constructor of MyClass, plz @JohnDoe

Comment: @JohnDoe I meant: since we can't see the code of that class, how are we to see that it's wrong? why would you use reflection if you don't need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `myClass.getConstructor(types)`, you need to pass class object. So you need to declare `String.class`, when you write `Double.TYPE`, this is used for primitive data type. Please refer this code

```
    Class myClass = Class.forName("com.citi.MyClass");

    Constructor cons= myClass.getConstructor(Double.TYPE, String.class);

    Object[] param = {1.0, "Hello"};
    Object instanceOfMyClass = cons.newInstance(1.0, "Hello");
```